# C# Get Xelement filled using List<T>

Tags: c#, xml

I have List with objects. I need get filled `XElement` blocks used objects of list.

Example:
Code:

```
var x = new XElement("root");
foreach (var rsltn in rsltnList)
{
    x.Add(CreateRsltnXml(rsltn));
}
```

Xml:

```
<Root>
   <MyXmlOfObject1>...</MyXmlOfObject1>
   <MyXmlOfObject2>...</MyXmlOfObject2>
   ...
   <MyXmlOfObjectN>...</MyXmlOfObjectN>
</Root>
```

Is there a better way to create one final XML without "Root" element or how do I create the XML better using "for" (or other cycle) that return next XML?

Xml:

```
<MyXmlOfObject1>...</MyXmlOfObject1>
<MyXmlOfObject2>...</MyXmlOfObject2>
   ...
<MyXmlOfObjectN>...</MyXmlOfObjectN>
```

Comment: An Xml can only have a root element, thus what you want breaks Xml convention, you can't do it

Comment: Well you can create a `List<XElement>`... but without a root element, you don't have an XML document.

Comment: Just use `x.InnerXml` to get all elements without the root element.

Comment: Ok, if can only get XML with root, maybe there is way to get XML without root of start XML?

Comment: Have you tried x.InnerXml liek I said in my previous comment ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound sorry, page is not updated. If possible, please show the example of the use solutions

Comment: No solution needed. Just add `string output = x.InnerXml` at the end of your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @CodeNotFound if I understood correctly - InnerXml return string, but I need to get it an XElement, which I will continue to be inserted into one or another unit of another XML(XElement).
If I describe what I want to get short -I need to implement the ability to create multiple identical blocks of XML (based on a List<T>), and then paste them in a particular place in another XElement

Comment: @Jon Skeet I agree. If you can not write without XElement root tag, how to return the tags from XElement, without returning the root tag as described in the example, the main issue? Maybe I'm trying to solve the problem of wrong - tell me how to get the result I needed

Comment: I can't tell what you need... It looks like you should just have a `List<XElement>` basically, but we don't know what you're trying to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help.
I found a solution to your problem. To get the result I needed I use

```
z.Add (x.Elements ());
```

Example:

```
var z = XElement("MainXml");
z.Add (x.Elements ());
```

I have a lot of XML type blocks:

```
<Root>
   <MyXmlOfObject1>...</MyXmlOfObject1>
   <MyXmlOfObject2>...</MyXmlOfObject2>
   ...
   <MyXmlOfObjectN>...</MyXmlOfObjectN>
</Root>
```

But I do not need the tag `<Root>` because tags within the `<Root>` I need to insert into another XML. Using `x.Elements();` command I get all the child elements with no root, which was needed.
Total I get needed result:

```
<MainXml>
   <MainXmlTag1>...</MainXmlTag1>
   <MainXmlTag2>...</MainXmlTag2>
   <MyXmlOfObject1>...</MyXmlOfObject1>
   <MyXmlOfObject2>...</MyXmlOfObject2>
   ...
   <MyXmlOfObjectN>...</MyXmlOfObjectN>
   <MainXmlTag4>...</MainXmlTag4>
   <MainXmlTagN>...</MainXmlTagN>
</MainXml>
```

If someone can offer the best solution to insert blocks of XML (XElements) into another XML (XElement) - I will be glad to try your option.